# How to deal with big integers in Elixir NIFs

Tags: c, elixir, biginteger, ffi, erlang-nif

I wrote an implementation of quicksort in C as an Elixir NIF. I'm aware that there is a BIF for that, I'm just doing this to teach myself NIFs.

Now my code works so far, that is, I can call `MyQuicksort.my_quicksort([1,100,2])` and get `[1,2,100]` returned as expected. However, elixir integers can be arbitrarily large and if I call `MyQuicksort.my_quicksort([123, 67_845_734_623_721_230_492_834, 1])` I get `~c"get_int gone wrong"`. This is my own error message but the point is that `enif_get_long` does not succeed for the large integer value. On https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif all `enif_get_$TYPE` functions for integer types have some hint like "Returns false if `term` is outside the bounds of the type".

My question is therefore if there is anyway to deal with such integers inside a NIF function.
Here is the code that I use to turn the elixir list into a C array.

```
static ERL_NIF_TERM my_quicksort(ErlNifEnv *env, int argc,
                                 const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[]) {
  uint size;
  if (!enif_get_list_length(env, argv[0], &size))
    return enif_make_string(env, "get_list_cell gone wrong", ERL_NIF_UTF8);
  if (size > INT_MAX)
    return enif_make_string(env, "list size too large", ERL_NIF_UTF8);
  long n[size];
  ERL_NIF_TERM head;
  ERL_NIF_TERM old_tail = argv[0];

  ERL_NIF_TERM new_tail;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (!enif_get_list_cell(env, old_tail, &head, &new_tail))
      return enif_make_string(env, "get_list_cell gone wrong", ERL_NIF_UTF8);
    if (!enif_get_long(env, head, &n[i]))
      return enif_make_string(env, "get_int gone wrong", ERL_NIF_UTF8);

    old_tail = new_tail;
  }

  quicksort(n, 0, size - 1);
```

I am aware why my program behaves the it does as I described. I feel like I am just missing the right `enif_get_$TYPE`function to deconstruct such integers.

Comment: There is no magic, [tag:c] simply does not support unlimited integers, so you might either leave it as is, or you are to write [an ad hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun's_tenth_rule) of erlang vm.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I'm not sure if I agree as I was not about to write a whole system that deals with concurrency, at most one that dynamically allocates memory/defines some kind of biginteger type. Actually what I just found is `enif_compare` to compare two erlang terms and so one can simply skip the `enif_get_long` part from my question and contruct a C array of `ERL_NIF_TERM`s and adjust the quicksort function to use the above compare function. I just did this and it works fine so far. I would be still be interested to hear if there are other/better ways to go about this =)

Comment: Well, I answered “if there is any way to deal with such integers inside a NIF function” question :) Glad you’ve found a workaround, but the conversion to [tag:c] would not work because there is no such type in [tag:c], that’s what I meant. I believe, answering your own question here is definitely worth it.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin it's a silly argument. Of course there are big integer types in C, they're just not included in the standard library. There may not be an easy way to get a biginteger value out of a nif term, but bigintegers not being in the standard library is not an argument for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, to answer the question myself, what I found so far is the `enif_compare` function that compares two `ERL_NIF_TERM`s.

That means I just have to transform the `ERL_NIF_TERM` that represents the list to sort into an array containing all its elements. Here is how the part of my code I listed in my answer looks after I incorporated this idea.

```
static ERL_NIF_TERM my_quicksort(ErlNifEnv *env, int argc,
                                 const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[]) {
  uint size;

  if (!enif_get_list_length(env, argv[0], &size))
    return enif_make_string(env, "get_list_cell gone wrong", ERL_NIF_UTF8);
  if (size > INT_MAX)
    return enif_make_string(env, "list size too large", ERL_NIF_UTF8);

  ERL_NIF_TERM n[size];
  ERL_NIF_TERM head;
  ERL_NIF_TERM old_tail = argv[0];
  ERL_NIF_TERM new_tail;

  for (uint i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (!enif_get_list_cell(env, old_tail, &n[i], &new_tail))
      return enif_make_string(env, "get_list_cell gone wrong", ERL_NIF_UTF8);

    old_tail = new_tail;
  }

  quicksort(n, 0, size - 1);

  return enif_make_list_from_array(env, n, size);
```

Then just have to adjust accordingly the types used in the `quicksort` function as well as the sort function it uses.

Note that if you forget to actually use `enif_compare(x,y) > 0` instead `x > y` you don't get an error, but still do not get the desired behavior for big numbers.

After I did this I can for example call

```
MyQuicksort.my_quicksort([
    123,
    97_845_734_623_721_230_492_834,
    67_845_734_623_721_830_492_834,
    111,
    67_845_734_623_721_230_492_111,
    9909
  ])
```

and actually get the sorted list back.